# Issue in updating multiple rows in MS sql server from php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple rows of a table via php using the below code :

```
$sql ="update [TableName] set status = 1 where producturl in (?)";
$param = array($purl);
$response = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$param);
```

where `$purl = ('h','a','b','c','d')`

The above code is not updating anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like below :

```
$purl = "('h','a','b','c','d')";
$sql ="update [TableName] set status = 1 where producturl in ".$purl;  
$response = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you are inserting **one single** parameter. The query translates to

```
update [TableName] 
set status = 1
where producturl in ("'h','a','b','c','d'")
```

So you could use **multiple parameters**

```
update [TableName] 
set status = 1
where producturl in (?,?,?,?,?)
```

or build a query string

```
$arr = join(',',$purl); 

$sql = "update [TableName] 
        set status = 1
        where producturl in ($arr)";
```

But then watch out for SQL injection. Always escape user input.

Comment: Good explanation of why it doesn't work. How would one do it properly?

Comment: You'd use a combination of `sqlsrv_prepare()` and `sqlsrv_execute()`, probably.